# How to integrate admob banner into Android app

Tags: android, admob

How to integrate admob into my Android app?

I have use this link: [google code](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals)
but I think there are not all the information needed.

Comment: what problem now your facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too certain about the tutorial, as I just worked through the API to get it to work.  Here's my code:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(OOKL.this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
LinearLayout al = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AdLayout);
al.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

adReq = new AdRequest();
adReq.setTesting(IS_DEBUG);
adView.loadAd(adReq);
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        setAdVisible(true);
    }

    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error) {
        setAdVisible(false);
    }

    public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad) {
    }

    public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) {
    }

    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad) {
    }
});

private void setAdVisible(boolean show) {
    View v = this.findViewById(R.id.AdLayout);
    v.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

This is pretty much all you need.  Here `IS_DEBUG` is my private variable controlling whether I'm running in test mode or live production.  `MY_AD_UNIT_ID` is the ad unit ID you get when you register the app with AdMob.  `AdLayout` is a LinearLayout that would contain the `AdView` - it's the first child in a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: thanks, for this source, but I'm new in android and I have many issues in source code right now.

Comment: Then I suggest you show your code and indicate where your problem is

Comment: thanks, I have add few changes, and everything work good! also I have tried use tutorial below and also all works for me.